# Updating a variable and change in the importing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two python classes in common.py:

common.py

```
class A:
    def func1:
             ...
    def func2:

class B:
    def func1:
          ....
    def func2

if volatile == 1:
    commonObj = A()
else:
    commonObj = B()
```

Now there are set of modules let's say:

user1.py,
user2.py, ...

which use `commonObj` like this below:

```
from common import commonObj

commonObj.func1()
commonObj.func2()
```

All these modules form one server, which continuously runs as a process.

I would like to ask how would I achieve this:
Suppose there is a way I can change the value of variable `volatile` any time, the user modules i.e user1.py, ... etc all should now access the updated value in `commonObj`, without having to restart the server.

Comment: changing code in the user*.py modules should be avoided.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: struggling with this for quite some time, ran out of ideas. Second, update my python knowledge.

Comment: i mean why do you want this functionality? what's the broader picture? see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/492979

Comment: Once they've imported `common.py`, they don't look at the file anymore. Changing the file won't affect the process at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing code in `user*.py` modules I can suggest this workaround:

```
class A:
    def func1:
        ...

class B:
    def func1:
        ...

class Common:
    def func1:
        if volatile == 1:
            return A.func1(self)
        else:
            return B.func1(self)

    ...

commonObj = Common()
```

Changing `volatile` value will have effect on what `func1` will be executed without restarting the server.

Comment: Thanks Sanyash, looks like a solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach towards problem is wrong. You want some dynamic behavior and trying to achieve it statically. Let us assume you, somehow, can change the value of `volatile` variable. Your `user.py` file will not ever get any benefit from the value of `commonObj` being changed because it will only call methods from this obj only once.

If, on the other hand, you have some piece of code that can run repeatedly (like a function), and using `commonObj` like this

```
def some_function():
    commonObj.func1()
    commonObj.func1()
```

You can dynamically get `commonObj` like this

**common.py**

```
def get_common_obj():
    if volatile == 1:
       return A()
    return B()
```

Now use this to get you object in user.py

```
from common import get_common_obj

common_obj = get_common_obj()
common_obj.func1()
common_obj.func2()
```

Comment: Nafees, your comment : "Your user.py file will not ever get any benefit from the value of commonObj being changed because it will only call methods from this obj only once." This point I am not understand properly. Why once ?